# multiple database entries or one with an array?

Tags: mysql, arrays

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_words` (
      `id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `user` int(15) NOT NULL,
      `word` int(15) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`_id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `words` (
      `words_id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `words_word` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`words_id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

I have the above tableS that currently stores words for each user so results could be like:

```
1 - 1 - 1
1 - 1 - 2
1 - 1 - 3
```

now the word bit is linked to the word table word=words_id

what I would like to know is this the best way to do this or would it be better to say have

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_words` (
  `id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `word` TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

1 - 1 - 1 2 3
```

and use an array to get the 3 results in the text field?

Comment: first option is better, as you should not have any intelligence inside the value of the field. Going forward you will not be able to do many of standard queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you only have 3 words, i would just put the word in to the user tables in one or 3 extra fields and not use these tables at all.

If you need to maintain a words table, you should use this connection table that you are using. So the first one is the way to go !